# VS Code insiders : Server download failed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue after an update of vscode insiders.

```
SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+alex"
SSH Resolver called for host: alex
Setting up SSH remote "alex"
Using commit id "0284236851a94b116f468345f6e98688a737015d" and quality "insider" for server
Install and start server if needed
> Installing to /home/alex/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/0284236851a94b116f468345f6e98688a737015d...
> Downloading with wget
> wget: unable to resolve host address ‘update.code.visualstudio.com’
> 16dc5c4c-c0ba-4e71-ae2b-9f44cbe3258d##25##
"install" terminal command done
Received install output: 16dc5c4c-c0ba-4e71-ae2b-9f44cbe3258d##25##
Server download failed
Downloading VS Code Server failed. Please try again later.
```

Everything work well before but I don't know how solve this. I try to reinstall old version, to kill all related process, search in logs, reboot...

I can still connect to my vm via ssh and via a terminal, but no more from vscode insiders

Someone to help me ?

Comment: There is no stable version for vscode insiders.
With vscode, i can't install all extensions to work properly on ssh, it ask for vscode-insiders.

Comment: Remote - Containers
Remote - SSH
Remote - SSH Explorer
Remote - SSH Editing Configuration Files
Remote - Development

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to solve this :
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/78#issuecomment-491229576

> This can be fixed by setting your proxies wget will use in .wgetrc in your home directory: ~/.wgetrc
> Example:
>
> ```
> use_proxy=on
> http_proxy=http://myproxy.proxy.net:3128
> https_proxy=http://myproxy.proxy.net:3128
> ```

This fixed my issue of wget hanging and it worked after doing this.